# How to load a file from desktop into Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am using an internal HIVE terminal console we use to interface with HIVE.  I have a csv with a list of account numbers.  I need to pull data from those account numbers form our tables in our database.  Normally I would just say where acct_num = XXXXXX but I have a list of 800 that I need to pull for.  I have tried creating a table and then loading the data using the infile but can not seem to get the hang of it.  This file is on my desktop but I have used winscp to move the csv file to my "directory" where I create my tables to.

This is the code I am using.  the account number is 15 digits and all numerical.  I am not sure if saving it as a .csv messes with the formatting of the number, but I have tried using create table as sting and as int.

```
drop table acorn_data.cj_test_accounts_load;
create table acorn_data.cj_test_accounts_load
(acct_num int);
load data inpath 
'/axp/buanalytics/csgsn/dev/Akhilesh/acorn_data/Test_accounts.csv' 
into table acorn_data.cj_test_accounts_load
```

I would like to if possible load this file into at least a temporary table so I can join it to the tables in our database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends where this "desktop" is and which exactly web tool you are using (hue? - I think you can't).

Then you have 2 options for loading data into hive from the file:

(1) Local - from the unix box on which hdfs is located (most likely not your "desktop")

(2) Not-Local - from hdfs (you can e.g. interact with webhdf - to dump file directly there: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html, or do `hadoop fs -put` from the mentioned unix box)

Documentation **REF**: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+dml#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables

Comment: We are using something called HIVE Terminal. I write my sql in an editory window and then the bottom half I can see the unix commands being passed and run.  I was hoping to use it from my local desktop on my machine but if not possible, It sounds like I need to get the file to the unix environment first.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
create table acorn_data.cj_test_accounts_load
(acct_num int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/cuddle/prod/sales.csv' INTO TABLE acorn_data.cj_test_accounts_load;
```